# C++ set container can't erase odd numbers

Tags: c++, set, containers

This program asks the user for a number, then stores all numbers up to and including it into a set container. The problem is that I to erase specific numbers, but I can't because the program freezes whenever I try to erase an odd number (signified by NUMBER below). It works fine when I erase even numbers though. However, I noticed that if I change the initial value of y to an even number, I become unable to erase even numbers. Here I have it set to an odd number. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
set<int>s;
set<int>::iterator cnt;
int n,x,y=1;
cout<<"Number: ";
cin>>n;
for(x=0;x<n-1;x++)
{
    s.insert(y);
    y++;
}
for(cnt=s.begin();cnt!=s.end();cnt++)
{
    if(*cnt==NUMBER)
    s.erase(cnt);
}
for(cnt=s.begin();cnt!=s.end();cnt++)
cout<<*cnt<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ugh - this is C++ not C, please put your variable declarations near their usage, or do this: `typedef set<int> MySet; MySet s; /* ... */ for(MySet::iterator cnt = s.begin(); cnt != s.end(); ++cnt)`

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `set::erase` says "*Iterators, pointers and references referring to elements removed by the function are invalidated. All other iterators, pointers and references keep their validity*."

```
for(cnt=s.begin();cnt!=s.end();cnt++)
{
    if(*cnt==NUMBER)
    s.erase(cnt);
}
```

As soon as you do `s.erase(cnt)`, `cnt` no longer refers to an element of the set. So when you do `cnt++`, you're trying to make it point to the "next element", but there is no next element.

One possible solution:

```
cnt = s.begin();
while (cnt != s.end())
{
    if (*cnt == NUMBER)
        s.erase(cnt++);
    else
        ++cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` has an `erase` that takes a key value instead of an iterator, so your entire removal process can be reduced to just: `s.erase(NUMBER);`.

You can also use `std::copy` to get the data from the set to output, so you end up with:

```
 s.erase(NUMBER);
 std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(),
           ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
```

Alternatively, you could filter out the undesired value when you copy the output from the set to standard output, something like:

```
std::remove_copy(s.begin(), s.end(),  
                 ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"), NUMBER);
```